# implement QAbstractItemModel with multi-columns tree view

Tags: qt4, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

i'm trying to implement QAbstractItemModel for multi columns tree view each column is a qstring but there is no data come up in the GUI till now and dont know why , help plz

```
#ifndef PACKETLISTMODEL_H
#define PACKETLISTMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractItemModel>
#include<QVector>
#include<QStringList>

class PacketListModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PacketListModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~PacketListModel();

    QModelIndex index(int row, int column,
                      const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void clear();
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                             int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    void appendPacket(QStringList*);
    QStringList* getPacket(int row);
signals:

public slots:

private:
    QVector<QStringList*> pkts;
};

#endif // PACKETLISTMODEL_H
```

==============================================================================

```
 #include "packetlistmodel.h"
    #include<QStandardItem>
    PacketListModel::PacketListModel(QObject *parent) :
        QAbstractItemModel(parent)
    {
    }
    QModelIndex PacketListModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const{
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        if (row >= pkts.count() || row < 0 || column >= 8)
            return QModelIndex();

        QStringList *pkt = pkts[row];

        return createIndex(row, column, pkt);

    }

    QModelIndex PacketListModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(index);
        return QModelIndex();
    }
    void PacketListModel::clear() {
        beginResetModel();
        pkts.clear();
        endResetModel();
    }

    int PacketListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        if (parent.column() >= 8)
            return 0;

        return pkts.size();
    }

    int PacketListModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED(parent);
        return 8;
    }
    QVariant PacketListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{



        if (!index.isValid())
            return QVariant();

        if (index.row() >= pkts.size() || index.row() < 0)
            return QVariant();

        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            //    QStringList pkt=static_cast<QStringList>(index.internalPointer());
            QStringList *pkt=pkts.at(index.row());
            if (index.column() == 0)
                return pkt->at(0);
            else if (index.column() == 1)
                return pkt->at(1);
            else if (index.column() == 2)
                return pkt->at(2);
            else if (index.column() == 3)
                return pkt->at(3);
            else if (index.column() == 4)
                return pkt->at(4);
            else if (index.column() == 5)
                return pkt->at(5);
            else if (index.column() == 6)
                return pkt->at(6);
            else if (index.column() == 7)
                return pkt->at(7);
        }
        return QVariant();

    }


    QVariant PacketListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                         int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/) const{
        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            if (section == 0) {
                return tr("Num");
            } else if (section == 1) {
                return tr("Time");
            } else if (section == 2) {
                return tr("Length");
            } else if (section == 3) {
                return tr("Source IP");
            } else if (section == 4) {
                return tr("Source Port");
            } else if (section == 5) {
                return tr("Protocol");
            } else if (section == 6) {
                return tr("Destination IP");
            } else if (section == 7) {
                return tr("Destination Port");
            }
        }
        return QVariant();

    }
    void PacketListModel::appendPacket(QStringList*pkt){
        if(pkt->size()==8){
             beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), pkts.size(), pkts.size());
            pkts.append(pkt);
          endInsertRows();
        }
    }

    QStringList* PacketListModel::getPacket(int row){
        if(row >= 0 || row <= pkts.count())
            return pkts[row];
    }
    PacketListModel::~PacketListModel(){
        pkts.clear();
    }
```

Comment: I don't like your `parent` method. Try to do like in a `simpletreemodel` example.

Comment: i want to do treeview with no children i need just like listview with multi columns

Comment: there is still invisible root.

Comment: what is the implementation of the index() and parent() if i need the treeview to be like list with multi columns no children in the items

Comment: Ok, I copied your example and tried to use without any changes. My data was shown, but there still was a `+`, which 'caused program crashing when clicking on it. Then I changed first line of `rowCount` method to `if (parent.isValid())` and `+` disappeared. Tried it on Linux with Qt 4.7.4, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "packetlistmodel.h"
#include<QStandardItem>
#include<QDebug>

PacketListModel::PacketListModel(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{

}
QModelIndex PacketListModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
        if (row >= pkts.size() || row < 0 || column >= 8)
            return QModelIndex();

        QStringList pkt = pkts.at(row);
        return createIndex(row, column, &pkt);
}

QModelIndex PacketListModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    return QModelIndex();
}
void PacketListModel::clear() {
    beginResetModel();
    pkts.clear();
    endResetModel();
}

int PacketListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
////////no children/////////////////////////
    if(parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    return pkts.size();
///////////////////////////////////////////

}

int PacketListModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 8;
}
QVariant PacketListModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const{



    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if (index.row() >= pkts.size() || index.row() < 0)
        return QVariant();

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && index.isValid()) {

        QStringList pkt = pkts.at(index.row());


        if (index.column() == 0)
            return pkt.at(0);
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            return pkt.at(1);
        else if (index.column() == 2)
            return pkt.at(2);
        else if (index.column() == 3)
            return pkt.at(3);
        else if (index.column() == 4)
            return pkt.at(4);
        else if (index.column() == 5)
            return pkt.at(5);
        else if (index.column() == 6)
            return pkt.at(6);
        else if (index.column() == 7)
            return pkt.at(7);
    }
    return QVariant();

}


QVariant PacketListModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                     int role /*= Qt::DisplayRole*/) const{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        if (section == 0) {
            return tr("Num");
        } else if (section == 1) {
            return tr("Time");
        } else if (section == 2) {
            return tr("Length");
        } else if (section == 3) {
            return tr("Source IP");
        } else if (section == 4) {
            return tr("Source Port");
        } else if (section == 5) {
            return tr("Protocol");
        } else if (section == 6) {
            return tr("Destination IP");
        } else if (section == 7) {
            return tr("Destination Port");
        }
    }
    return QVariant();

}
bool PacketListModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index,const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
        QStringList pkt =value.toString().split("\t");
        int idx = index.row();
        pkts.replace(idx, pkt);//problem was here it should take value not pointer
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        result =  true;
    }

    return result;
}
bool PacketListModel::insertRow(int position, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position);
    QStringList qs;
    pkts.insert(position,qs);
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}

PacketListModel::~PacketListModel(){
    pkts.clear();
}
```

Comment: it run fine but its too slow and the data cuz it to hang i dont know why